# C# How to change font of a label

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, label

A form with a label and a button 'Options'. By clicking the button a new form opens with 2 radio buttons 'Font1' and 'Font2', and two buttons 'Apply' and 'Cancel'. Upon selecting one of the radio buttons and clicking 'Apply' will make the label on the first form change the font face. The problem is how to change the font as in from say Tahoma to Arial or to any other font face of the label.

Options form code for apply button, which if was clicked will return dialogresult.ok == true and change the font of the label on the first form:

```
private void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioFont1.Checked)
    {
        mainForm.lblName.Font.Name = "Arial"; 'wrong attempt 
    }
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

Declaration of the label on first form so that it is visible to second form:

```
public static Label lblName = new Label();
```

...

```
private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblName = lblBarName;
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`Font.Name`, `Font.XYZProperty`, etc are readonly as `Font` is an immutable object, so you need to specify a new [`Font`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.aspx) object to replace it:

```
mainForm.lblName.Font = new Font("Arial", mainForm.lblName.Font.Size);
```

Check the constructor of the `Font` class for further options.

Comment: Font 'Arial' does not support style 'Regular'. What does that mean?

Comment: Font in its entirety is immutable; not just the Name property

Comment: @Aaron - I said `Font.XYZProperty` to infer all properties. I forgot the word to describe it, so thanks for reminding me :).

Comment: @GenericTypeTea My comment was prior to your edit and addition of the XYZProperty reference...and you're welcome :)

Comment: @TheEnd - it sounds to me as though your default Arial font has been replaced. There's no reason why Arial shouldn't have the style for regular as it's a basic font. Try it using `FontStyle.Bold` and `FontStyle.Italic`. You may have to get the font off the windows CD. You can check if it exists by going to Notepad, then Format...>Font. Select Arial and I bet Regular will not be listed.

Comment: Weird, but replacing "Arial" with "Arial Black" makes the whole thing work. Perhaphs my "Arial" font is corrupted.

Comment: @TheEnd- that'd be by guess, see my previous comment.

Answer (score 9):

You can't change a Font once it's created - so you need to create a new one:

```
  mainForm.lblName.Font = new Font("Arial", mainForm.lblName.Font.Size);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer on my question.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a new Font

```
mainForm.lblName.Font = new Font("Arial", mainForm.lblName.Font.Size);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer on my question.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there was not an actual full code answer, so as i come across this, i have created a function, that does change the font, which can be easily modified. I have tested this in

### - XP SP3 and Win 10 Pro 64

```
private void SetFont(Form f, string name, int size, FontStyle style)
{
    Font replacementFont = new Font(name, size, style);
    f.Font = replacementFont;
}
```

Hint: replace Form to either Label, RichTextBox, TextBox, or any other relative control that uses fonts to change the font on them. By using the above function thus making it completely dynamic.

```
    /// To call the function do this.
    /// e.g in the form load event etc.

public Form1()
{
      InitializeComponent();
      SetFont(this, "Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);  
      // This sets the whole form and 
      // everything below it.
      // Shaun Cassidy.
}
```

You can also, if you want a full libary so you dont have to code all the back end bits, you can download my dll from Github.

[Github DLL](https://github.com/DroitechGames/Droitech.TextFont)

```
/// and then import the namespace
using Droitech.TextFont;

/// Then call it using:
TextFontClass fClass = new TextFontClass();
fClass.SetFont(this, "Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.lblMessage.Font = new Font("arial", this.lblName.Font.Size);
```

Comment: please edit your answer, and add an explanation of how your code solves the problem