# Change font of a label with custom font

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Is possible change the font of label in C# with a custom font. EX.: I need change the font to *Bookman Old Style* and in Visual Studio doesn't have this font.

Is possible add? How?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573916/using-custom-fonts-in-my-winform-labels ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is the answer!
[Font in labels][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939255/c-sharp-how-to-change-font-of-a-label

good job ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [PrivateFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx) to load the font (See the `AddFontFile` and `AddMemoryFont`). You then use the font normally for label control.

```
PrivateFontCollection pfc = new PrivateFontCollection();
pfc.AddFontFile("C:\\Path To\\YourFont.ttf");
label1.Font = new Font(pfc.Families[0], 16, FontStyle.Regular);
```

Comment: but the user need to have the font?

Comment: @illDev:you can embed your font in your application.

Comment: how embed I my font in app?

Comment: thx, this link is helpful too http://dotnet-coding-helpercs.blogspot.com.br/

Comment: I have added my font in resources but how add I the font from resources with addFontFile?