# Change font of custom TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have created custom `TextBox`, but when I set it's `Font` to a new one it doesn't work :

```
    public class TextLayer : TextBox
    {
        public TextLayer()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor |
                     ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                     ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                     ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);


            BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

            //font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 20);
           Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 20);

            Size = new Size(22, 22);


        }


        protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnTextChanged(e);

            var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text, Font);

            if (size.Width < 30)
                Width = 30;
            else
                Width = size.Width;

            if (size.Height < 30)
                Height = 30;
            else
                Height = size.Height;
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
             base.OnPaint(e);
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(
                e.Graphics, ClientRectangle,
                Color.White, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Dotted,
                Color.White, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Dotted,
                Color.White, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Dotted,
                Color.White, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Dotted);


        }
}
```

what do I miss here, that force the `TextBox` to render it's default font?

Edit:
[C# How to change font of a label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939255/c-sharp-how-to-change-font-of-a-label) I'm already doing that in my code and it's not working ,so how is that a duplicate ?

Comment: Remove the ControlStyle.UserPaint, also remove the BorderStyle.None if you want to draw the borders

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# How to change font of a label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939255/c-sharp-how-to-change-font-of-a-label)

Comment: TextBox is the grand-daddy of the controls in your toolbox.  Goes all the way back to 1985.  You are seeing what 30 years of appcompat looks like, you turned on the time-machine.  That hokey font is called "Terminal", TrueType didn't happen until 1991.  Archaeology is interesting, isn't it :)